# Chat and the SE toolbar

Tags: feature-request, chat

I quite often spend plenty of time in chat without ever navigating back to DBA.se.

Is there any way of making the Stack Exchange toolbar (as it appears on DBA.se) appear at the top of the chat page so that I can see notifications, rep changes etc?

I'll just give this a little edit in the vague hope that it'll be noticed now that the new toolbar has been rolled out. Pretty please? ;)

EDIT: 2 years on, I wonder if it'll ever happen?

Comment: I think this is a question for the main meta site, since chat and the toolbar are not specific to dba.SE.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nah it should be fine here. I'm keeping an eye on it. :)

Comment: @Aarthi ok, but wouldn't such functionality, were it implemented, be applicable to other sites other than dba.SE? Or do you want to keep it here so that it doesn't get thwapped and draconianized?

Comment: Well, every meta is as valid as MSO. If this needs more attention, we can migrate there if needed. :)

Comment: Thanks @Aarthi :)

Comment: What Aarthi didn't say is that the Community Team watches all the metas and moderators/community are only encouraged to migrate things to [metase] that belong to all the sites, but in general, we moderators are to encourage users to post even engine questions to the local meta. But yes, Aaron, normally we would encourage that if asked before the question were posted. It's just not needed. Have you seen the RSS feeds on StackExchange.com that let you watch all the sites for common tags (like [tag:sql-server])?

Comment: @jcolebrand I follow the DBA.se Oracle tag via RSS, but wasn't aware of the site-wide option

Comment: Yeah they keep an eye out especially for `feature-request` and `bug` items.

Comment: +1 yes please this would be lush

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Yes it should. This would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 6):

As [suggested in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39131543#39131543) by [Shog9](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3435/shog9):

> In the meantime, try [Top Bar for Chat Rooms](https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms) (stackapps)
>
> > Provides a fully functional top bar, including realtime notifications, easy chat server switching, and fast room list searching, at the top of all chat rooms. Keep tabs on your inbox and site activity while chatting.
> >
> > [image: screenshot]

For installation steps see https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info